# Vectorizing addition of subarray

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

Let's say I have two (large) vectors `a=[0 0 0 0 0]` and `b=[1 2 3 4 5]` of the same size and one index vector `ind=[1 5 2 1]` with values in {1,...,length(a)}. I would like to compute

```
for k = 1:length(ind)
    a(ind(k)) = a(ind(k)) + b(ind(k));
end
% a = [2 2 0 0 5]
```

That is, I want to add those entries of `b` declared in `ind` to `a` including multiplicity.

```
a(ind)=a(ind)+b(ind);
% a = [1 2 0 0 5]
```

is much faster, of course, but ignores indices which appear multiple times.

How can I speed up the above code?

Comment: what is the expected behaviour for an index which appears several times? would you like to perform the addition on this index only once?

Comment: No, I would like to add the index as often as it appears. Just like in the for-loop above.

Comment: I do not understand why does a(ind)+b(ind) ignore indices which appear multiple times.

Comment: @GameOfThrows It's in the assignment back to `a` that causes the issue. It's like saying `a([1 1]) = [1 2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `unique` to identify the unique index values and use the third output to determine which elements of `ind` share the same index. We can then use `accumarray` to sum all the elements of `b` which share the same index. We then add these to the original value of `a` at these locations.

```
[uniqueinds, ~, inds] = unique(ind);
a(uniqueinds) = a(uniqueinds) + accumarray(inds, b(ind)).';
```

If `max(inds) == numel(a)` then this could be simplified to the following since `accumarray` will simply return `0` for any missing entry in `ind`.

```
a(:) = a(:) + accumarray(ind(:), b(ind));
```

Comment: The result I would expect is ``[13 12 9]``.

Comment: This still gives ``[15 14 9]``, I think.

Comment: @Julian Oh ok I just saw what the issue was. We only need to apply `accumarray` to `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach based on [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
a(:) = a(:) + accumarray(ind(:), b(ind(:)), [numel(a) 1]);
```

**How it works**

`accumarray` with two column vectors as inputs aggregates the values of the second input corresponding to the same index in the first. The third input is used here to force the result to be the same size as `a`, padding with zeros if needed.